# Website is pushed away by (porn) advertising

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, users

Some website visitors are seeing (porn) advertisement instead of my website.
The website is "pushed away" after a few seconds and another website (mostly porn advertising) is taking over.
It does not happens to all users, for instance, I did never see it.
Also it is not happening to those users everytime.

My hosting says it has nothing to do with them, and the website seems OK.

So, it must be on userside. Agree?

Does anyone know how to solve this? Is it a website problem?
I am using an free WordPress theme

Comment: You mean, you are using a re-targeting ads; so that your website visitors when visit other sites - they see ads by Google AdSense; and here, they first see your website ad, and then after it automatically taken over by porn ads, Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If that's true, then you would first like to check settings with your Google Ads settings. By mistake, while selecting categories, someone has sected porn as a category, so your ad is displayed with porn ads. Another reason could be your visitors also visit porn sites and their browser has cookies of porn sites. That's why they are seeing these ads.

Comment: No, I am not using any re-targeting ads. I am not using Google Ads at all. But I will double check if someone did.
Regarding the visits of other porn sites could trigger this, I've received this "bug" from people which I don't believe they visit porn sites

Comment: could you make it clear what do you mean by "Some website visitors are seeing (porn) advertisement instead of my website." where do they see these ads? What is your website all about?

Comment: This smells like your site has been hacked. The code that does this will be well hidden so you may want to replace your code with a saved copy.

Answer (score 1):

One of two things had happened: malicious code has been placed on your site, or more than likely **you're using a non reputable ad source, or didn't configure your ad preference correctly**

For instance, I used to use PopAds on my company's website, until Google flagged the links from them as malicious and a lot of them were for pornographic or similar content

At this point, it looks like your ads, not malware